# How to setup event log for .NET Core 3.0 Worker Service

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, worker

I'm working with the new Worker Service app template with .NET Core 3.0 Preview and am trying to add event logging using the `AddEventLog` method. However, I cannot see any of my logs via the Event Viewer in Windows.

I have a very simple Worker app setup and have configured logging in the `Program.cs` file as follows:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseWindowsService()
    .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
    {
        logging.AddEventLog(new EventLogSettings()
        {
            SourceName = "MyTestSource",
            LogName = "MyTestLog"
        });
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    });
```

I then have some logging statements in the `Worker.cs` file as follows:

```cs
private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

public override async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"Worker started at: {DateTime.Now}");
    await base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
}

public override async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _logger.LogInformation($"Worker stopped at: {DateTime.Now}");
    await base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
}

protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation( $"Worker running at: {DateTime.Now}");
        await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

To setup the event logs, I ran the following from an elevated Powershell prompt:

`New-EventLog -LogName MyTestLog -Source MyTestSource`

If I open the Event Viewer I can see "MyTestLog" listed below "Applications and Services Logs".

Then, to set up my Worker as a Windows service, I ran the following commands from an elevated command prompt:

`dotnet publish -o publish` (Publishes project and outputs to publish directory)

`sc create MyTestService binPath=<path to exe in publish directory>`

The service is created successfully, and I can see it in the Services viewer application. From there, I manually start the service and then check back in the Event Viewer and no logs are displayed.

I was expecting there to be some logs. However, the "MyTestLog" section remains empty in the Event Viewer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So I was able to find the issue reported [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/1839).

Essentially it boils down to a change in the latest .NET Core 3.0 Preview where Event Logs are filtered at the warning level by default now. Thus, you cannot see any information logs.

The fix was to simply edit the `appsettings.json` file to look like the following:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },
    "EventLog": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This overrides the default set and allows information logs to be viewed again.

Comment: Thanks for your post. it definitely solves my problem. But I got a small issue. I can see the log under the WindowsLogs, but not under the Applications and Service Logs section. I was expecting a new item, but nothing is created. Any idea.

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked in this environment, but I do remember needing to refresh my logs to see everything. Also, I definitely remember seeing logs in those sections as well. However, this was when all of this was in Preview so there may have been more changes since.

Comment: it actually works. But a simple refresh does not work. Instead, I need to restart the event log application to see it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 5.0.0.

What's posted here got me close but didn't totally solve my problem.  The logs were still listed under the "Application" Log Name even through I was resetting it via the ConfigureLogging method.

In order to fix this I had to clear out the providers.  This seems like a defect to me with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.

The solution below does NOT require running the powershell script mentioned in the OP (New-EventLog -LogName MyTestLog -Source MyTestSource)

Working solution for me, nothing else required...

Program.cs:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.AddConsole();
    
        logging.AddEventLog(new EventLogSettings()
        {
            LogName = "TSEServiceLog",
            SourceName = "TestSavvyExecuteService"
        });
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
    })
    .UseWindowsService();
```

appsettings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },
    "EventLog": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Solved same issue in .NET 6